# Wordpress WooCommerce CSV File set multiple categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a CSV file with the which looks like this right now

Categories
CATEGORIE1 > SUBCATEGORIE

If I import this into WooCommerce the checkbox of the subcategorie is only checked in the product. I want to have that the product have checked the Categorie1 and Subcategorie checkboxes.

As seen in the picture the main categorie needs to be checked too. But I dont know how this is possible automaticly

[image]

Comment: So your import file should be slightly different to get that…

Comment: How different??